# Video Live Stream in Expo React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, video-streaming, mobile-application

I am developing a mobile app for the school bus using Expo, React Native and Firebase. When a driver turns on the camera, the live video should be visible to school authority. For that how to achieve a live video streaming in Expo React Native.

I already tried [video sdk](https://app.videosdk.live/quick-start/conferencing/build-from-scratch/mobile/react-native). but it is not supporting for Expo. Is there any other way to do it other than eject from expo?